# Network related information related to the Azure services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-appservice

I am new to Azure.

Where can we find information like Source Port, Destination Port, Protocol, Direction, CIDR , Service Tag for Azure services like Azure App configuration , Service bus, Application Insights.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some of this is public information, some is not.  The closest that you're likely to get is the set of [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=56519) for the public cloud.